# Breastfeeding for 3-5 minutes and feeds every hour

Tags: infant, breastfeeding, nutrition

So my son is 3 months old and the most he breast feeds at a time is 5-6 minutes, then he falls asleep or unlatches. And he’ll feed every hour or hour and a half. He’s been gaining weight, has plenty of wet diapers and poop diapers every other day, and after eating he seems content and doesn’t really cry unless he’s super tired. But I’m just worried and concerned he’s not getting the hind milk.

Comment: This behavior is called "clustering" or "[cluster feeding](https://www.pregnancybirthbaby.org.au/cluster-feeding)". It's stressful for the mother but not bad for the baby.

Comment: @henning, with respect, I’d say it’s not quite clear from the question if this is cluster feeding or not. I’ve always taken "cluster feeding" to be a short term thing (a few hours of on/off in an evening, maybe every evening for a while, say). Regardless, my conclusion is the same: not bad for the baby. Inconvenient for the mother, but it’ll pass.

Comment: @Pam I see. Perhaps it's shades of grey.

Comment: Hello sorry I didn’t clarify. My son feeds every hour every single day he’ll feed for 5 minutes unlatch then the next hour he’ll feed again. The only time he doesn’t feed every hour is in the middle of the night he feeds maybe every 4 hours

Comment: @CourtneyLozada, then I’d +2 the answer below if I could! Your baby has found a custom routine that currently (mostly!) works for both of you. Don’t worry about the clock (unless there are other signs something is wrong).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The beauty of breastfeeding is that it’s a pretty self-regulating process and that mother and baby adapt to each other quickly.

Speaking from experience, I had two *very* different babies. One would leisurely feed for half an hour (slowly but constantly, clearly enjoying the time), the other was done in just a few minutes. She still has a rather no-nonsense attitude towards food, she eats to live while the other lives to eat, as they say.

As long as your child is growing fine, seems content and satiated and is filling his diapers, I can only recommend to stop worrying.

As for the hind milk, it’s possible that you baby is just thirsty (e.g. in hot weather or climate, when they are prone to asking for frequent quick sips), but I think it’s more likely that your body has adjusted to your baby well enough that he gets what he needs.